# How to convert a DateTime with milliseconds into epoch time with milliseconds

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have data in hive table in the below format.

```
2019-11-21 18:19:15.817
```

I wrote a sql query as below to get the above column value into epoch format.

```
val newDF = spark.sql(f"""select TRIM(id) as ID, unix_timestamp(sig_ts) as SIG_TS from table""")
```

And I am getting the output column SIG_TS as `1574360296` which is not having milliseconds.

How to get the epoch timestamp of a date with milliseconds?

Comment: What is the datatype for "sig_ts" in hive ? a String ?

Comment: its of type timestamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple way: Create an UDF since spark's built-in function truncates at seconds.

```
import java.sql.Timestamp

val fullTimestampUDF = udf{t: Timestamp => t.getTime}
val df = Seq("2019-11-21 18:19:15.817").toDF("sig_ts")
    .withColumn("sig_ts_ut", unix_timestamp($"sig_ts"))
    .withColumn("sig_ts_ut_long", fullTimestampUDF($"sig_ts"))

df.show(false)
+-----------------------+----------+--------------+
|sig_ts                 |sig_ts_ut |sig_ts_ut_long|
+-----------------------+----------+--------------+
|2019-11-21 18:19:15.817|1574356755|1574356755817 |
+-----------------------+----------+--------------+
```